'Error fetching property data: [TypeError: Failed to parse URL from buy.php]
I am trying to access and send a data from the php side called buy.php to my javascript and it gives me the error 'Error fetching property data: [TypeError: Failed to parse URL from buy.php]
i checked the relative location and still not working
// Fetch property data from PHP
function fetchPropertyData() {
    fetch('buy.php') //
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            // Log the fetched data to the console
            console.log(data);
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching property data:', error));
}

// Call the function to fetch property data when the page loads
fetchPropertyData();

my php code `$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'realstate_main');
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
// Prepare SQL query to fetch all property details
$sql = "SELECT Email,phone,Address, Size,type, Price,location, Bedroom, Bathroom,listingfor,discription,pictureURL FROM Sellhouse where address='lebu'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

// Check if any properties are found
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // Fetch all property details
    $properties = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $properties[] = $row;
    }

    // Close database connection
    $conn->close();

    // Output property details in JSON format
   echo json_encode($properties);
} else {
    // No properties found
    echo json_encode(['error' => 'No properties found']);
}
`


At which line do you get the error?

Line 3 in the fetch method
